# Updating Data from Kivy Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, kivy

I have a problem on updating data that I want to insert to excel. At first, I create the data and it work successfully without error. After I want to insert new data from Kivy, it doesn't work. Error said that the process denied by PC. I had watch tutorial and it seem my problem still unsolved. Here is my code from VSCode:

```
Window.size = (500, 500)
```

outWorkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("staff.xlsx")
outSheet = outWorkbook.add_worksheet()

class Menu(Screen):
pass

class Enter(Screen):

```
input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
input2 = ObjectProperty(None)
input3 = ObjectProperty(None)
input4 = ObjectProperty(None)
input5 = ObjectProperty(None)
input6 = ObjectProperty(None)

def clear(self):
    self.ids.inherent_input.text = ''
    self.ids.inherent2_input.text = ''
    self.ids.inherent3_input.text = ''
    self.ids.inherent4_input.text = ''
    self.ids.inherent5_input.text = ''
    self.ids.inherent6_input.text = ''

def btn(self):
    self.L = ()
    print("Name: " + self.input1.text,
        "Activity/Programme: " + self.input2.text,
        "Date: " + self.input3.text,
        "Place: " + self.input4.text,
        "Time from: " + self.input5.text,
        "Time to: " + self.input6.text)

    
    staff = ({"Name": [str(self.input1.text)], "Program/Activity": [str(self.input2.text)], "Place" : [str(self.input3.text)], "Date": [str(self.input4.text)], "Time From" : [str(self.input5.text)], "Time To" : [str(self.input6.text)]})
    self.L = pd.DataFrame(staff)

    self.input1.text = ''
    self.input2.text = ''
    self.input3.text = ''
    self.input4.text = ''
    self.input5.text = ''
    self.input6.text = ''

    print(self.L)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('staff.xlsx') as writer:
        self.L.to_excel(writer)
```

class Info(Screen):
pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
pass

kv = Builder.load_file('window.kv')

## class MyLayout(Widget):

class WindowApp(App):
def build(self):
return kv

if **name** == '**main**':
WindowApp().run()

And here is my kv file:

```
WindowManager:
Menu:
Enter:
Info:
```

:
    name: "MainMenu"

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height

    padding: 10
    spacing: 15

    Button:
        id: enter
        text: "Enter"
        on_release: app.root.current = "enter"

    Button:
        id: info
        text: "Information"
        on_release: app.root.current = "info"

    Button:
        id: exit
        text: "Exit"
        on_press: quit()
```

:
name: "enter"

```
input1: inherent_input
input2: inherent2_input
input3: inherent3_input
input4: inherent4_input
input5: inherent5_input
input6: inherent6_input

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height

    padding:10
    spacing:10

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10

        Label:
            text: "Name"
            font_size: 20
        
        TextInput:
            id: inherent_input
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            text: "Activity/Programme"
            font_size: 20

        TextInput:
            id: inherent2_input
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            text: "Place"
            font_size: 20

        TextInput:
            id: inherent3_input
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Date"
            font_size: 20

        TextInput:
            id: inherent4_input
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10

        Label:
            text: "Time from"
            font_size: 20

        TextInput:
            id: inherent5_input
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: "to"
            font_size: 20

        TextInput:
            id: inherent6_input
            multiline: False

    BoxLayout:

        padding: 15
        spacing: 15

        
        Button:
            id: clear
            text: "Clear"
            font_size: 12
            on_press: root.clear()

        Button:
            id: back
            text: "Back to Menu"
            font_size: 12
            on_release: app.root.current = "MainMenu"
            

        Button:
            id: submit
            text: "Submit"
            font_size: 12
            on_press: root.btn()
```

:
name: "info"

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    padding: 15
    spacing: 15

    Label:
        id: information
        text: "This is just a test, an Alpha version of Prototype"
        font_size: 20
        bold: True
        italic: False
        outline_color: (0,0,0)

    Button:
        id: returnBack
        text: "Return"
        on_release: app.root.current = "MainMenu"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: It's actually not a programming error, more like user adminstration error since I'm not updating the data instead I'm saving the data with the same name.

Comment: Error: xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied: 'file path'

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting can mean multiple things.

Are you trying to open a directory?

If so, don't do it. It will most likely result in the error you mentioned.

Is the file you are trying to opened anywhere else?

You may have to close it, for python to open it. You probably have experienced this before when trying to delete a file in the explorer, that is opened somewhere else. Windows won't let you do this. Check whether the file in question is opened before trying to access it.

Comment: I had no issues for opening file, the problem come when I tried to update the excel with the new data I want to implement. As I use append method, it also show the same result.

Comment: Owh, okay now I get it, I must close the file than run again the system so it will updated.

Comment: I had other problem, how can I update the excel sheet without overwrite previous data? Is there any method can I implement?

Comment: So, instead of editing the original, you want to save an edited copy of the original. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, I want to save the data to existing excel file without overwrite the data that previously save.